# sourcetree GIT - what kind of files to include, best practices

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm completely new to SourceTree and somehow new to version control systems.  What are the best practices of the types of files to include in your repository?  Do you include 3rd party DLLs that you aren't changing?  What about your final compiled code or do you just include the source code?  It doesn't make sense to me to include anything 3rd party or your own compiled version of the code, but in watching some of the tutorials online, I see these being included.  On the otherhand, I've experienced the pain of having to go find and download the libraries that developers have assumed I had when I downloaded their Git projects.  I suspect that the answers might be different depending upon what language your are programming in and whether you have something like Maven or not.

I have been tasked with using Git for both Java and C# so any help in the direction as to what I should or shouldn't include would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Concatonate one or two or three of these depending on your platform and language: https://github.com/GitHub/gitignore

Comment: This differs by project and opinion.

Comment: And don't forget about tag'd releases. Will you include symbol files for the shipped binaries to make sense out of a crash dump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really has much todo with your personal preferences, the language you are using and the project dependencies.

In general you should try to only add files to version control that are actually required for the project development, as version control is in this case mainly a development tool.

Here is some general advice:

- Do not include compiled code if it is possible to compile it from the project source files.
- Do include required libaries which can not easily/automatically be installed and ignore the others.
- Do not include temporary and environment specific files, like your IDE config or log files.

Comment: *"Do not include compiled code if it is possible to compile it from the project source files"* - are you certain about that? Have you ever tried to precisely recreate a binary so that a crash dump from the field makes sense? Its not enough to check out a revision. Everything from environments and toolchains to dependent libraries have to match or be recreated.

Comment: For the sake of debugging your compiled code it is helpful. Though you have to remember that fixing and recompiling on another system would not use the old environment anyway and therefor you can't know if you actually fixed the issue or it's just non existent in your environment. So for the sake of version control in distributed development i would certainly not include compiled code and rather share the failing binary elsewhere if the error does not persist after recompiling on another system. It's also helpful for debugging, as you then know that the bug is environment specific.

Comment: @jww it's like i said also a matter of personal preference and your project dependencies. I offered general advice and in general you should share your project so it is able to be recompiled on another system. Most languages offer tools to provide exact version control of dependend libaries. Additionally compiled binaries will change on each source code change, so you will commit an extra changed file every time. These files can also get pretty big in larger projects and you do not want to commit several mb of data for every code change.